# Javascript typeof() behaves unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, typeof

A variant of W3Schools...http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_typeof ....
Seems to think '4' is a string, is this expected? I don't think so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>The global function typeof() returns the type of variables:</p>
<button id='Clothing-4' onclick="myFunction(this)">4</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction(button) {
    var buttonID=button.id; //Button ID is [type]-[action]
    var buttonparts = buttonID.split('-');
    itemType=buttonparts[0];
//Tried using buttonparts[1];
    var buttonAction=buttonID.substr(buttonID.indexOf('-')+1,buttonID.length)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    "|"+buttonAction+"|" + "<br>" + 
    typeof(buttonAction) + "<br>" + 
    typeof("john") + "<br>" + 
    typeof(3.14) + "<br>" +
    typeof(false) + "<br>" +
    typeof({name:'john', age:34});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it tells you it's a string, then it's a string. The `typeof` operator has no will that it should endeavor to fool you. It can only behave according to its implementation which follows a standard.

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, it's operator, `id` is a string...

Comment: As cookie monster said - it's just a character typed onto the screen, as part of a larger string. Why do you think it would be a number?

Comment: tried `typeof 4` from my firebug console. its number. :)

Comment: Yes, but that's not what he's got. He's got a `"4"`, extracted from `"Clothing-4"`. Try `typeof("4")`.

Comment: I advise you to rely on MDN (mozilla Developer Network) rather than w3schools. MDN has more information and it is more accurate. They know typeof is an operator, for instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is expected. The button's `id` is represented as a string; you know this as you are using string related functions (`substr()`) to extract the character `4`. Notice how I said character. If you pull a character (or characters) from a string, expect them to be strings. JavaScript will not automatically parse every character you extract from a string to see if it's a number. You must do that yourself with something like `parseInt()`.

Remember, `typeof` doesn't do any parsing. It looks at the actual type of the object representing the value you pass it. It will point out the difference between `4` being a `Number` and `"4"` being a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a value of type string, the `typeof()` will return it as string, as you specified `typeof('4')`, the 4 is specified as string so it returns string

If you pass`typeof(4)` then it will return number

Answer (score 0):

The value of the button element is here a string. The string value is "4". The object holding "4" is a string object. The first byte of this string object has the hexadecimal value 34 and not decimal value 4.

Therefore function **typeof** returns correct **string** as type of the object. You would need the function [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the number string into a number value.